Is there a way to convert SVG without going through a file?
For an add-on I want to use additional data coming from the SVG for further steps after importing.
I know that I could do the following:

import SVG
parse SVG and extract information
post-process the imported objects using IDs to connect objects to SVG elements

but I'd rather

parse SVG
convert SVG elements into objects one by one
post-process the converted element immediately

Is there a way to do things with this flow, rather than import and post-process all imported elements?
